# C# class to xml using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi all I am having 3 classes as follows

```
public class Main
{
    public List<B> BList{ get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        ListA = new List<A>();
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<A> ListA { get; set; }
}
public class A
{
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int Weightage { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert it to XML using linq as follows after adding data

```
Main main = new Main ();
var xEle = new XElement("Root", 
    from x in main.BList
    from te in x.A 
    select new XElement("Child", 
        new XElement("Weightage", te.Weightage), 
        new XElement("FName", x.FirstName),
        new XElement("LName", x.Email) ));
```

Which is giving me output as follows

```
    <Root>
  <Child>
    <Weightage>20</Weightage>
    <FName>ABC</FName>
    <LName>abc@abc.com</LName>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Weightage>20</Weightage>
    <FName>ABC</FName>
    <LName>abc@abc.com</LName>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

What I need is as follows

```
    <Root>
  <Child>
    <Weightage>10</Weightage>
    <FName>ABC</FName>
    <LName>abc@abc.com</LName>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Weightage>20</Weightage>
    <FName>ABC</FName>
    <LName>abc@abc.com</LName>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

Fiddler here https://dotnetfiddle.net/x6Hj01

Comment: Can you add some character somewhere to indicate differences (between current output and expected output) as I can't tell atm - Used an online comparer and now see the difference (20 weightage should be 10)

Comment: Maybe use serialization? I have found it useful when converting to xml string and back to object.

Comment: weightage for both the child in output is same ie 20

Comment: Where did you assign `Weightage`? Or to be more correct, when you adding files `List<A>`?

Comment: There is nothing to do with your code, your data initialization part is wrong. I appreciate the fact, that you are creating your xml manually, but there is tons of already defined classes that you can use.

Comment: Agree with @japesu and would suggest using serialization.  More straightforward

Comment: @Dotnet - Edit question to include code from fiddler in question, instead in link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Problem:

Your problem isn't with the linq but with how you populate the data:

```
Master m=new Master();
m.BList =new List<B>();

B b=new B();
b.FirstName ="ABC";
b.Email="abc@abc.com";

A a=new A();    //Line 1
a.Rating = 1;
a.Weightage =10;

b.ListA.Add(a); //Line 2

a.Rating = 2;   <--- problem here
a.Weightage =20;

b.ListA.Add(a); //Line 3
m.BList.Add(b);
```

You instantiate `a` only one (at "Line 1") and then populate it with data and add it to the list (at "Line 2"). Then you reassign data to it and add it again to list (at "Line 3").

When you assign values again into `a` you are actually still updating the same reference as before. Therefore you get the same object twice in the list and with the same values, as it is the same object.

> The Solution:

To solve it add `A a = new A()` just before the line of the problem.

> Suggestions and improvements:

1. A cleaner way all together is to use object initializers:

   ```
   Master m=new Master
   {
       BList = new List<B>
       {
           FirstName = "ABC",
           Email = "abc@abc.com",
           AList = new List<A>
           {
                new A { Rating = 1, Weightage = 10 },
                new A { Rating = 1, Weightage = 20 },
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. As for the way of constructing your xml I suggest using
   serialization. [Look here for some examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)
3. Another improvement is to initialize the collections this way:
   (possible from C# 6.0)

   ```
   public class Main
   {
       public List<B> BList { get; set; } = new List<B>()
   }
   public class B
   {
       public List<A> ListA { get; set; } = new List<A>()
   }
   ```

Comment: Yea, that's why I flagged this _off-topic seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")_

Comment: Did the OP somewhere post that initialization code or are you guessing? I can't see that code anywhere so am a bit confused - people are upvoting but to me it looks like you are debugging code that you have assumed exists which doesn't feel like something upvotable...

Comment: @Chris - Did not assume anything - code is in Fiddler link

Comment: @GiladGreen: Aha! I didn't think to look for code in links! I was about to be disapproving at you for not encouraging the OP to improve his question by including the relevant code but see you have now. :) (also +1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to serialize your Data is to use DataContract Serializer.

You can find more information [on msdn Here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

It would be easier than your solution :)